# How to build debug boost static libraries with 'clang-win' toolset?

Tags: c++, boost, clang, lib

I have a problem building debug versions of the standard and runtime support libraries using `clang-win` toolset (with `msvc` toolset everything works as expected)

Specifically I'm trying to build `mt-gd` variant of the lib file so I add `runtime-debugging=on` switch as [Boost docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) say but to no avail
Here's what I get:

1) `b2 toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 --with-filesystem variant=release`
generates `libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x64-1_72.lib` *[correct]*

2) `b2 toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=64 --with-filesystem runtime-debugging=on variant=debug`
generates `libboost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib` *[correct]*

3) `b2 toolset=clang-win address-model=64 --with-filesystem variant=release`
generates `libboost_filesystem-clangw9-mt-x64-1_72.lib` *[correct]*

4) `b2 toolset=clang-win address-model=64 --with-filesystem runtime-debugging=on variant=debug`
generates `libboost_filesystem-clangw9-mt-d-x64-1_72.lib` ***[incorrect]***
Should be `libboost_filesystem-clangw9-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib`

Same behavior for `boost 1.67`, `boost 1.68` and `boost 1.71`
Anybody have an idea what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be solved in [version 1.74](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0). I tried running

```
b2 toolset=clang-win address-model=64 variant=debug --with-filesystem
```

producing the file: `stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-clangw9-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib`, as expected.

If you have to stick to the boost version, for me simply renaming the library files did also work. Alternatively, you can skip the auto-linking and explicitly specify the library by defining the preprocessor macro `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem. Building with runtime-debugging=on or off would build .lib files without the g tag.

`b2 -a -j16 toolset=clang-win cxxflags="-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SILENCE_CXX17_OLD_ALLOCATOR_MEMBERS_DEPRECATION_WARNING" architecture=x86 address-model=64 runtime-link=static runtime-debugging=on --build-type=complete --layout=tagged variant=debug,release --without-mpi --without-python stage --stagedir=clangw10`

Would produce files like **`libboost_thread-mt-sd-x64.lib`** and linking against it breaks the linking process like:

`LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin\lld-link.exe CMakeFiles\test.dir\cmake_pch.cxx.obj CMakeFiles\test.dir\resources\win.rc.res CMakeFiles\test.dir\main.cpp.obj /out:test.exe /implib:test.lib /pdb:test.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:windows E:\SDKs\boost_1_72_0\stage\lib\libboost_thread-mt-sd-x64.lib E:\SDKs\boost_1_72_0\stage\lib\libboost_chrono-mt-sd-x64.lib E:\SDKs\boost_1_72_0\stage\lib\libboost_date_time-mt-sd-x64.lib E:\SDKs\boost_1_72_0\stage\lib\libboost_atomic-mt-sd-x64.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\test.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\test.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1) with the following output:`

`E:\Workspace\test\build\x64-Debug\lld-link : error : could not open 'boost_thread-clangw10-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib': no such file or directory`

`E:\Workspace\test\build\x64-Debug\lld-link : error : could not open 'libboost_date_time-clangw10-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib': no such file or directory`

`E:\Workspace\test\build\x64-Debug\lld-link : error : could not open 'libboost_chrono-clangw10-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib': no such file or directory`

It looks like the libraries depend on runtime-debugging either way but without b2 being able to produce those I'm pretty much stuck on this.

**UPDATE**
I was able to successfully link my programm with cmake by adding the 'g' in the .lib's filename and building boost with **--layout=versioned**

In order to link the proper files I had to add in **CMakeLists.txt**

`set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")`